# Why Interface written in Kotlin disappears after reboot in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, interface, kotlin

I have an interface written in Kotlin to make REST calls (which works so far):

```
import io.reactivex.Observable
import okhttp3.ResponseBody
import retrofit2.Response
import retrofit2.http.Body
import retrofit2.http.POST

const val PUSH_ENDPOINT = "prices/v1"

interface ArticleSearchRestAdapter {
    @POST("$PUSH_ENDPOINT/articles/search")
    fun register(@Body articlerequest: ArticleRequest): Observable<Response<ResponseBody>>
}
```

As i said, this works so far, but after a **REBOOT** of PC in Android Studio the icon turns

from [image: this] 
to [image: this].

Then other classes which use ArticleSearchRestAdapter cannot find this interface and are marked red.

Is that a bug in Androuid Studio? What is wrong?

IDE: Android Studio 3.0 Beta 6

Comment: Maybe if you set the `package` at the top of the file? `package xxx.xxx.xxx`

Comment: @KevinRobatel It's package is defined. I skipped it to save space. It happens after I reboot my PC.

Comment: It's so soon that we can use kotlin in real projects, android developers has enough pain with this platform and somethings like kotlin add to this pain :)

Comment: It's not the latest beta. Check for the Kotlin plugin being active; it might have failed starting with AS.

Comment: May be try to invalidate cache and restart. also check the Kotlin plugin. I have been using Android Studio Canary 3.0x and have not found this bug

Comment: are you sure you wants to keep const `val PUSH_ENDPOINT = "prices/v1"` outside of `interface` ? try keeing it inside

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it shouldn't even look like the first pic you've posted. Will you please try this. Add the interface by right-clicking on the rest package, then new, kotlin file/class and then choosing the **Interface** in the Kind field. Now if there's no error in the Interface its icon should be a green circle, not that.